# following code countdown not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script is for countdown timer, but its show only Days Hours Minutes Seconds (**1d 0h 0m 0s** ). Can anyone suggest me the solution for the same? I changed everything but failed, can anyone suggest me what to do with it?

```
let countdown="";
    let closingdate = "2021-08-04";
    let countDownDate = new Date(closingdate).getTime();
    let x = setInterval(function() {
    let Startingdate = "2021-08-03";
    let StartcountDownDate = new Date(Startingdate).getTime();
    let distance = countDownDate - StartcountDownDate;
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
  
    countdown = $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");;     
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Closed";
        }
                                
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: What exactly want to do?

Comment: want to start countdown from start date to end date if 0 then closed text show in div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue of your countdown is that you always use start time without any increasing time. You need to add one second to start time on each interval.

Here is working sample based on your own code with jQuery:

```js
let closingdate = "2021-08-04";
let countDownDate = new Date(closingdate).getTime();
let Startingdate = new Date("2021-08-03");

let x = setInterval(function () {
    Startingdate.setSeconds(Startingdate.getSeconds() + 1);
    let StartcountDownDate = Startingdate.getTime();
    let distance = countDownDate - StartcountDownDate;
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

    countdown = $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");;
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Closed";
    }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
```

Here is new working sample with pure JavaScript and some new styles:

```js
 var speed = 1;
 function getTimeRemaining(endtime, starttime) {
     starttime.setSeconds(starttime.getSeconds() + speed);
     const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(starttime);
     const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
     const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
     const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
     const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

     return {
         total,
         days,
         hours,
         minutes,
         seconds
     };
 }

 function initializeClock(id, endtime, starttime) {
     const clock = document.getElementById(id);
     const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
     const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
     const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
     const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

     function updateClock() {
         const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime, starttime);

         daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
         hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
         minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
         secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

         if (t.total <= 0) {
             clearInterval(timeinterval);
         }
     }

     updateClock();
     const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, speed * 1000);
 }

 const deadline = new Date("2021-08-04");
 const starttime = new Date("2021-08-03");
 initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline, starttime);
```

```css
 h1 {
     color: #396;
     font-weight: 100;
     font-size: 40px;
     margin: 40px 0px 20px;
 }

 #clockdiv {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     color: #fff;
     display: inline-block;
     font-weight: 100;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 30px;
 }

     #clockdiv > div {
         padding: 10px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         background: #00BF96;
         display: inline-block;
     }

     #clockdiv div > span {
         padding: 15px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         background: #00816A;
         display: inline-block;
     }

 .smalltext {
     padding-top: 5px;
     font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
    <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv">
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Update based on refresh page and closing tab**

You can use `localStorage` to make sure after any refresh, `starttime` does not reset. And also when tab is closing you can keep current time in `localStorage` with `onbeforeunload` event and when page is loaded calculate the time that browser is closed and add the duration to `starttime`:

```
let closingdate = "2021-08-04";
let countDownDate = new Date(closingdate).getTime();

let Startingdate = localStorage.getItem("Startingdate");
if (!Startingdate)
    Startingdate = "2021-08-03";

Startingdate = new Date(Startingdate);
var OncloseDate = localStorage.getItem("OnCloseTab");
if (OncloseDate) {
    let duration = new Date().getTime() - new Date(OncloseDate).getTime();
    Startingdate = new Date(Startingdate.getTime() + duration);
}

let x = setInterval(function () {
    Startingdate.setSeconds(Startingdate.getSeconds() + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("Startingdate", Startingdate)
    let StartcountDownDate = Startingdate.getTime();
    let distance = countDownDate - StartcountDownDate;
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

    countdown = $('#countdown').html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");;
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Closed";
    }

}, 1000);


window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("OnCloseTab", new Date());
};
```

Comment: everytime refresh the page same counter timer start and its not 0 for example today is 5th aug then after counter still start ideally today its 0

Comment: @Nilesh Ok just put the time in the local storage. Are you familiar with localStorage?

Comment: No , can you please explain me how to do it

Comment: @Nilesh Note that we can't guarantee the browser is always open. maybe client close the browser. only refresh supported by localStorage. is it ok?

Comment: i agree with your advise but start date less then end date it will 0 client just want to know how many time remaining for close store can we do it like this if browser closed and reopen remaining time will show on counter

Comment: @Nilesh Yes we can. I updated the answer to keep current time when tab is closed and when you reopen the browser I calculate the time browser was closed and add the duration to start time. Enjoy :)

Comment: @Nilesh I test the code even after one hour browser was closed and everything was OK

Comment: Yes its working correctly Thank You so much